# Find at least 2 customer in the same area who likes at least one pizza sold in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

**Tables in SQL Query**

1. Likes(cname, pizza)
2. Customers(cname, area)
3. Restaurants(rname, area)
4. Sells (rname, pizza, price)

Refer to: sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5be81e/1 (Consist of code and database schema)

**Expected Results**: A list of restaurants that fulfill the below conditions

**Conditions**:

1. At least 2 customers like at least one pizza sold by the restaurant. 
   (They do not necessarily like the same pizza sold by the restaurant, customer and the restaurant do not have to be in the same area)
2. Restaurant must sell at least 3 pizzas
3. At least one the pizzas sold by the restaurant must be cheaper than $20

**My SQL Code:**

```
SELECT r.rname
FROM restaurants r
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1
         FROM sells s 
         INNER JOIN likes l ON l.pizza = s.pizza
         GROUP BY c.area
         HAVING COUNT(l.pizza) >= 2
         WHERE s.rname = r.rname 
         AND s.pizza >=3 
         AND s.price <20
         )
```

I incorporated this code based several other SQL posts which promotes the use of WHERE EXIST. Now i'm stuck at the hardest part of condition 1.

Update: All answers are excellent. Turns out customer and the restaurant do not have to be in the same area

Comment: Which condition do you think D or G don't match?

Comment: Most likely the first condition. Because i checked the other two and both seems to match though. It's very weird.

Comment: Customers `c` and `l` are both from `central`. They both like `marinara`. Restaurants D and G are from `central` and sell `marinara`.

Comment: Yeah. That's why. I'm trying out to see if customer and the restaurant do not have to be in the same area will work or not now. :)

Comment: What should the desired result look like?

Comment: It should only consist of L. :)

Comment: If you are weakening the condition, you will get more (or same) results - not less.

Comment: Yeah. That's true. I'll go ahead and accept the answer because they fulfill the previous conditions nicely. Thanks for all your efforts!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without any subqueries but with a huge join:

```
SELECT r.rname
FROM restaurants r
JOIN sells s ON s.rname = r.rname
LEFT JOIN likes l on l.pizza = s.pizza
LEFT JOIN customers c
  ON  c.area  = r.area
  AND c.cname = l.cname
GROUP BY r.rname
HAVING 1
   AND COUNT(DISTINCT c.cname) >= 2 -- cond. 1
   AND COUNT(DISTINCT s.pizza) >= 3 -- cond. 2
   AND MIN(s.price) < 20            -- cond. 3
ORDER BY r.rname
```

[Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jWvU8Q67P6FdXoHUceXW1k/0)

This however is probably not very efficient. For a better performance I would write one query for condition 1 and one query for conditions 2 and 3. Then Join them:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT r.rname
    FROM restaurants r
    JOIN sells s ON s.rname = r.rname
    JOIN likes l on l.pizza = s.pizza
    JOIN customers c
      ON  c.area  = r.area
      AND c.cname = l.cname
    GROUP BY r.rname
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT c.cname) >= 2
) t1
NATURAL JOIN (
    SELECT s.rname
    FROM sells s
    GROUP BY s.rname
    HAVING MIN(s.price) < 20 
       AND COUNT(*) >= 3
) t2
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/26b0b2/78)

Here is a third method, which is quite the same as the second one, but uses an EXISTS subquery instead of a JOIN.

```
SELECT r.rname
FROM restaurants r
JOIN sells s ON s.rname = r.rname
JOIN likes l on l.pizza = s.pizza
JOIN customers c
  ON  c.area  = r.area
  AND c.cname = l.cname
GROUP BY r.rname
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT c.cname) >= 2
   AND EXISTS (
     SELECT s.rname
     FROM sells s
     WHERE s.rname = r.rname
     HAVING MIN(s.price) < 20 
        AND COUNT(*) >= 3
)
```

If the customers who liked a pizza don't need to be from the same area as the restaurant, you will just need to remove the condition `c.area  = r.area`. And than you would also not need to touch the tables `restaurants` and `customers`. So the query would become shorter:

```
SELECT s.rname
FROM sells s
LEFT JOIN likes l on l.pizza = s.pizza
GROUP BY s.rname
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT l.cname) >= 2
   AND COUNT(DISTINCT s.pizza) >= 3
   AND MIN(s.price) < 20
```

Answer (score 1):

For condition 1, use `GROUP BY restaurants.rname` and `HAVING COUNT(distinct Customers.cname) > 1`:

```
    SELECT restaurants.rname
    FROM restaurants
    inner join
    customers
    on restaurants.area = customers.area
    inner join
    likes
    on customers.cname = likes.cname
    inner join
    sells
    on likes.pizza = sells.pizza and restaurants.rname = sells.rname
    where
    restaurants.rname in 
    (select r.rname from 
    restaurants r
    inner join
    sells s
    on r.rname = s.rname
    group by r.rname
    having count(  s.pizza) >= 3  
    and min(s.price) < 20)

    group by restaurants.rname
    having count(distinct customers.cname) > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You were on the right track with the `WHERE EXISTS` idea but bunching up all 3 conditions in that single `EXISTS` can make your query really messy and things start to become confusing.  In your original query, you might have needed subqueries if you were to follow through with just one.

Instead, continue to use your `WHERE EXSISTS` but separate your conditions into 3 `EXISTS` conditions like so:

```
SELECT r.rname
FROM restaurants r
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1
             FROM likes l
             INNER JOIN customers c ON c.cname = l.cname
             INNER JOIN sells s ON s.pizza = l.pizza
             WHERE s.rname = r.rname
             GROUP BY s.rname, l.cname
             HAVING COUNT(l.pizza) >= 2
             )
  AND EXISTS(SELECT 1
             FROM sells s
             WHERE s.rname = r.rname
             GROUP BY s.rname
             HAVING COUNT(s.pizza) >= 3
             )
  AND EXISTS(SELECT 1
             FROM sells s
             WHERE s.rname = r.rname
               AND s.price < 20
             )
```

Each one of the `EXISTS` statements correspond to your conditions.  This makes it more intuitive for yourself and you don't have to worry about mashing everything into just one `EXISTS`.

Comment: Great answer! It is clear and easy to understand. But i have one last problem. I'm still trying to figure out why D & G appear before i accept the answers. The answer should only consist of L.

Comment: Is there an `L` missing in the `restaurants` table in the SQLFiddle?  I see `L` in `sells` but not in `restaurants`.

Comment: I added 2 `INNER JOIN's` that were missing for condition 1.  You may have to update your SQLFiddle.